# How to calculate how much Ip Addresses have between two Ip Addresses?

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

I have two Ip Addresses, and I want to count how many Ip Addresses there are in the range between the two.

Example:

```
IP_START = "127.0.0.0"

IP_END = "127.0.1.1"

SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS = 257
```

Does anyone know if python has anything to help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 12):

Short solution using the `ipaddress` package.

```
import ipaddress
ip1 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(unicode('127.0.0.0')))
ip2 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(unicode('127.0.1.1')))
print ip2 - ip1
```

Comment: It's not good.
Example:
IP_START = "127.0.0.1"
IP_END = "127.0.0.10"

SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS = 10

And yours answer is: 9

When i ask how many Ip Addresses there are in the range between the two, i mean with them .

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. Add one to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
IP_START = "127.0.0.0"
IP_END = "127.0.1.1"
diffs = [int(b)-int(a) for a,b in zip(IP_START.split('.'), IP_END.split('.'))]
SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS = 0
for d in diffs:
    SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS *= 256
    SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS += d
SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS += 1

>>> IP_START = "127.0.0.0"
>>> IP_END = "127.0.1.1"
>>> diffs = [int(b)-int(a) for a,b in zip(IP_START.split('.'), IP_END.split('.'))]
>>> SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS = 0
>>> for d in diffs:
...     SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS *= 256
...     SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS += d
... SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS += 1
...
>>> SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS
257
```

Comment: It's not good.
Example:
IP_START = "127.0.0.1"
IP_END = "127.0.0.10"

SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS = 10

And yours answer is: 9

When i ask how many Ip Addresses there are in the range between the two, i mean with them .

Comment: @MultiPython: In that case, your example is also wrong (it shows 257, when it should show 258). I've updated to add your feature request

Answer (score 2):

this sounded fun so here you go

```
class IPV4ADDR:
    def __init__(self, *parts):
        if len(parts) > 4:
            raise Exception("Unknown IP Address:%s" % parts)
        if len(parts) == 1 and isinstance(parts[0], basestring):
            parts = map(int, parts[0].split("."))
        if len(parts) != 4:
            raise Exception("Unknown IP Address:%s" % parts)
        self.parts = parts

    def __int__(self):
        parts = self.parts
        return parts[0] << 24 | parts[1] << 16 | parts[2] << 8 | parts[3]

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return int(self) - int(other)

    def __add__(self, other):
        #not sure how to "add" ip addresses so ill just OR them
        numeric_val = int(self) | int(other) 
        return IPV4ADDR(numeric_val & 0xFF000000,
                      numeric_val & 0xFF0000,
                      numeric_val & 0xFF00,
                      numeric_val & 0xFF)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d.%d.%d.%d" % self.parts

a1 = IPV4ADDR("127.0.0.0")
a2 = IPV4ADDR("127.0.1.1")

print a2 - a1 #257
```

Comment: It's not good.
Example:
IP_START = "127.0.0.1"
IP_END = "127.0.0.10"

SUM_OF_IP_ADDRESS = 10

And yours answer is: 9

When i ask how many Ip Addresses there are in the range between the two, i mean with them .

Comment: it gives the right answer ... it matches your output above ... there are only 9 between those two ... you cant redefine the numeric system'

Answer (score 1):

Python3 version of Max's answer

```
import ipaddress
ip1 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(str('127.0.0.0')))
ip2 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(str('127.0.1.1')))
print(ip2 - ip1)
```

Answer (score 0):

some short solution

```
from ipaddress import ip_address

def ips_between(IP_START, IP_END):
    return int(ip_address(IP_END)) - int(ip_address(IP_START))
```